# Access to current track's URL in SoundCloud website with UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, soundcloud

I am trying to load Soundcloud.com with `UIWebView`, but unfortunately soundcloud forces you to user the app.You can search and listen to tracks,but you can not copy or share tracks. I am trying to access the URL but only gives me :`https://m.soundcloud.com`:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print(webview.request?.url?.absoluteString)
    }
```

Is there anyway to copy the current track's URL ? or at least force Soundcloud website to work and show all contents without forcing to use their app.

Comment: Why are you using the deprecated UIWebView? (I ask because I'm looking at figuring this out, but didn't really want to use the deprecated version).

Comment: @MattH it doesn’t matter I can use webkit

Comment: ok thx -- it'll be a matter of deciphering the DOM and injecting javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's here:

```
let title = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "$('.sound__title').html()")
```

Just put that code wherever you want to check the song title. That's for a `UIWebView`

Comment: Thanks but this gives me song title not URL . I need something like this `https://soundcloud.com/chipotlemexicangrill/savorwavs-pang-remix`

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution :

```
let currentURL =  webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.location.href")!
```

it gives me the exact page url